# BPMN Correct use of Pools

Tags: bpmn

I am still struggling with the concept of a pool in bpmn as I have a situation in which I am still not sure weather my modelling is right or not. Consider the following situation:
One company creates a document, checks it and sends it to another one. This company checks the document and sends it back if it is not correct. Then the first company changes the document and sends it again to the second one. In principal this can happen a lot of times and my first idea to model this process is the following diagram:

[image]
I think this diagram violates the condition that a participant (represented by a pool) needs to have full control of its process flow. Is there any way to avoid placing the whole process in one pool or is my understanding wrong and the diagram correct?

Answer (score 0):

your diagram is worg!
i think "Pool" represents the process!
(however, there are some who disagree!)

you can break process to two process : "send" and "confirmation" processes and place every into one Pool (and every Pool must have one "Start Activity" and "End Activity") or place whole process in one pool this depends on your modeling.